# Spring: locate the folder with properties using systemEnvironment variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources

I have a Spring project named 'finman'.

[The directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQJWs.png)

As you can see on the image the folder with properties (named 'config') is on the same level as 'src'. So I need to locate that path using

```
systemEnvironment['FINMAN_ROOT']
```

The code fragment from 'spring-mvc.xml' responsible for the resource bundle location:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:cacheSeconds="60"
      p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8">
    <property name="basenames" value="file:///#{systemEnvironment['FINMAN_ROOT']}/config/messages/app"/>
</bean>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables set in OS:

Windows: https://www.chem.gla.ac.uk/~louis/software/faq/q1.html

Linux: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/

After it do not forget to restart java (or IDE), as they get environments, when started.